# Extracting dates in R

Tags: r

I am working with time-series in an online fashion, so I need to extract dates sequentially(one at a time). I used:

```
dates<- seq(as.Date(today), by="days", length=10)
dates[1]
           [,1]
2016-06-24   NA
```

I would like to extract each element as we do in matrices for example:

```
mat<- matrix(c(1,2),ncol=1, nrow=2)
mat[1,1]
[1] 1
```

How can I just get the date part i.e, 2016-06-24 by indexing or in a loop?

Comment: Not quite get your problem. But this seems to get a series of dates. `dates<- seq(as.Date(lubridate::today()), by="days", length=10)`.

Comment: I have edited the question, Is it more clear now?

Comment: So you just want to print the dates one at a time?

Comment: Is it possible to have `[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-25"
[2] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-26"
[3] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-27"
...`instead ?

Comment: `today<- "2016-06-24"` I just wrote today to avoid writing the date. I am doing forecasting in an online fashion, so later I will need to bind dates with numeric data and convert it to time series, thus, I want to be able to access dates sequentially. Hope that clarifies the question further.

Comment: @rawr. Yes. That is another way to get the sequence.

Comment: @rawr. Unfortunately I can't install `dplyr` to check what it does. I am getting: `download of package ‘dplyr’ failed`

Comment: @Vic Sure, well the numbers you'd talking about there are indexing the result number from the expression, so if you extract it one at a time the result number is always `[1]` but if you do them all at once then you get `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. Of course you could always print your own index with a loop counter variable and that would produce the result the way you want.

Comment: @Hack-R--Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if I have misinterpreted your question. This exacts them sequentially and prints it to the screen:

```
dates<- seq(as.Date(Sys.Date()), by="days", length=10)

for(i in 1:length(dates)){
  print(paste("I have extracted the following date:", dates[i]))
}

[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-25"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-26"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-27"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-28"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-29"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-06-30"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-07-01"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-07-02"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-07-03"
[1] "I have extracted the following date: 2016-07-04"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `paste()` function to print them all at once with some text and combine it with `dates` object.

```
  today <- Sys.Date()
  today
  # [1] "2016-06-26"

  dates<- seq(as.Date(today), by="days", length=10)
  dates
  #  [1] "2016-06-26" "2016-06-27" "2016-06-28" "2016-06-29" "2016-06-30"
  #  [6] "2016-07-01" "2016-07-02" "2016-07-03" "2016-07-04" "2016-07-05"

  paste("I have extracted the following date: ",dates)
  # [1] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-06-26"
  # [2] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-06-27"
  # [3] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-06-28"
  # [4] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-06-29"
  # [5] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-06-30"
  # [6] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-07-01"
  # [7] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-07-02"
  # [8] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-07-03"
  # [9] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-07-04"
  #[10] "I have extracted the following date:  2016-07-05"
```